# How to unit test Kotlin suspending functions

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mvp, coroutine

I follow the MVP pattern + UseCases to interact with a Model layer. This is a method in a Presenter I want to test:

```
fun loadPreviews() {
    launch(UI) {
        val items = previewsUseCase.getPreviews() // a suspending function
        println("[method] UseCase items: $items")

        println("[method] View call")
        view.showPreviews(items)
    }
}
```

My simple BDD test:

```
fun <T> givenSuspended(block: suspend () -> T) = BDDMockito.given(runBlocking { block() })

infix fun <T> BDDMockito.BDDMyOngoingStubbing<T>.willReturn(block: () -> T) = willReturn(block())

@Test
fun `load previews`() {
    // UseCase and View are mocked in a `setUp` method

    val items = listOf<PreviewItem>()
    givenSuspended { previewsUseCase.getPreviews() } willReturn { items }

    println("[test] before Presenter call")
    runBlocking { presenter.loadPreviews() }
    println("[test] after Presenter call")

    println("[test] verify the View")
    verify(view).showPreviews(items)
}
```

The test passes successfully but there's something weird in the log. I expect it to be:

- "[test] before Presenter call"
- "[method] UseCase items: []"
- "[method] View call"
- "[test] after Presenter call"
- "[test] verify the View"

But it turns out to be:

- [test] before Presenter call
- [test] after Presenter call
- [test] verify the View
- [method] UseCase items: []
- [method] View call

What's the reason of this behaviour and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found out that it's because of a `CoroutineDispatcher`. I used to mock `UI` context with `EmptyCoroutineContext`. Switching to `Unconfined` has solved the problem

## Update 02.04.20

The name of the question suggests that there'll be an exhaustive explanation how to unit test a suspending function. So let me explain a bit more.

The main problem with testing a suspending function is threading. Let's say we want to test this simple function that updates a property's value in a different thread:

```kotlin
class ItemUpdater(val item: Item) {
  fun updateItemValue() {
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) { item.value = 42 }
  }
}
```

We need to somehow replace `Dispatchers.Default` with an another dispatcher only for testing purposes. There're two ways how we can do that. Each has its pros and cons, and which one to choose depends on your project & style of coding:

**1. Inject a Dispatcher**.

```kotlin
class ItemUpdater(
    val item: Item,
    val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher  // can be a wrapper that provides multiple dispatchers but let's keep it simple
) {
  fun updateItemValue() {
    launch(dispatcher) { item.value = 42 }
  }
}

// later in a test class

@Test
fun `item value is updated`() = runBlocking {
  val item = Item()
  val testDispatcher = Dispatchers.Unconfined   // can be a TestCoroutineDispatcher but we still keep it simple
  val updater = ItemUpdater(item, testDispatcher)

  updater.updateItemValue()

  assertEquals(42, item.value)
}
```

**2. Substitute a Dispatcher.**

```kotlin
class ItemUpdater(val item: Item) {
  fun updateItemValue() {
    launch(DispatchersProvider.Default) { item.value = 42 }  // DispatchersProvider is our own global wrapper
  }
}

// later in a test class

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --- This block can be extracted into a JUnit Rule and replaced by a single line ---
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Before
fun setUp() {
  DispatchersProvider.Default = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}

@After
fun cleanUp() {
  DispatchersProvider.Default = Dispatchers.Default
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Test
fun `item value is updated`() = runBlocking {
  val item = Item()
  val updater = ItemUpdater(item)

  updater.updateItemValue()

  assertEquals(42, item.value)
}
```

Both of them are doing the same thing - they replace the original `Dispatchers.Default` in test classes. The only difference is how they do that. It's really really up to you which of them to choose so don't get biased by my own thoughts below.

*IMHO:* The first approach is a little too much cumbersome. Injecting dispatchers everywhere will result into polluting most of the classes' constructors with an extra `DispatchersWrapper` only for a testing purpose. However Google [recommends this way](https://youtu.be/KMb0Fs8rCRs?t=840) at least for now. The second style keeps things simple and it doesn't complicate the production classes. It's like an RxJava's way of testing where you have to substitute schedulers via RxJavaPlugins. By the way, `kotlinx-coroutines-test` [will bring the exact same functionality](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1365) someday in future.

Comment: it is recommended to inject the coroutine scope & dispatchers instead: https://craigrussell.io/2019/11/unit-testing-coroutine-suspend-functions-using-testcoroutinedispatcher/

Comment: I don't like the idea to pollute every constructor with a "DispatchersProvider". It's a little too much cumbersome. I prefer the RxJava way of testing - replace global Schedulers via RxJavaPlugins. It's far more convenient and it doesn't complicate the code.
By the way, this approach will be available for Coroutines as well: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1365

Comment: hello, any idea on how we can find a solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68634896/test-for-suspend-function-making-http-get-call-fails

Answer (score 12):

I see you found out on you own, but I'd like to explain a bit more for the people that might run into the same problem

When you do  `launch(UI) {}`, a new coroutine is created and dispatched to the "UI" Dispatcher, that means that your coroutine now runs on a different thread.

Your `runBlocking{}` call create a new coroutine, but `runBlocking{}` will wait for this coroutine to end before continuing, your `loadPreviews()` function creates a coroutine, start it and then return immediately, so `runBlocking()` just wait for it and return.

So while `runBlocking{}` has returned, the coroutine that you created with `launch(UI){}` is still running in a different thread, that's why the order of your log is messed up

The `Unconfined` context is a special `CoroutineContext` that simply create a dispatcher that execute the coroutine right there on the current thread, so now when you execute `runBlocking{}`, it has to wait for the coroutine created by `launch{}` to end because it is running on the same thread thus blocking that thread.

I hope my explanation was clear, have a good day